# How to select last 7 days from data from today's date?

Tags: sql, database, subquery, vertica

I know are many ways to get what I searching, actually I found the solution here on the forum, but the problem is that I don't really know why is not working, this is my try:

```
select * From ModeloBI.CORP.T_LOGI_RN_Planeacion_Entregas 
Where ModeloBI.CORP.T_LOGI_RN_Planeacion_Entregas.Fecha_de_modificacion >= dateadd (day, -7, GetDate());
```

(where *Fecha_de_Modificacion* is the field with the date of the record)

When I execute this query I get next error:

**"Column 'day' does not exist"**

Do you know guys, who is this happening? or if there are other method to get what I want?

Thanks by the way, have a nice day,

Answer (score 0):

Use `interval`:

```
ModeloBI.CORP.T_LOGI_RN_Planeacion_Entregas.Fecha_de_modificacion >= current_date - interval '7' day
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * From ModeloBI.CORP.T_LOGI_RN_Planeacion_Entregas 
Where ModeloBI.CORP.T_LOGI_RN_Planeacion_Entregas.Fecha_de_modificacion >= dateadd(dd,-7,getdate());
```